# Repeating Javascript function execution with time delay

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm about to make some JS functionality that will

- execute one function for previously predefined number of times
  (iterations)
- **make a delay after each function execution for previously predefined number of seconds**

One big request is that solution must be Ajax compatibile.

Say:

```
<script>
functon my_function(numberoftimes, secondsdelay){
//do ajax requests for numberoftimes, separeted by secondsdelay
$.ajax(
            {
                type: "GET/POST",
                url: "exampleurl",
                data: "key=value",
            }
        )
}
<script>

<button onclick="my_function(3,1)">Do it</button>
```

how?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you heard of [`window.setTimeout()'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)?

Comment: I was actually thinking of for loop in JS, but if there's better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function my_function(numberoftimes, secondsdelay) {
    //do ajax requests for numberoftimes, separeted by secondsdelay
    var i = 0;

    function doIt() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET/POST",
            url: "exampleurl",
            data: "key=value",
            complete: function() {
                if (i++ < numberoftimes) {
                    setTimeout(doIt, secondsdelay * 1000);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    doIt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
setInterval()
```

in your ajax callback and keep a contor of how many times you ran the function.
and on the callback just do

```
callback : function() {
    contor++;
    if(contor < 3) {
       setInterval(yourFunction, delayMilliseconds)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use -

window.setInterval("javascript function",milliseconds);

Ref -

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp